# Changing an answer after a bug has been reported

Tags: discussion

In [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221601/white-border-around-icons/), the person has noticed something that appears to be a bug. I first wrote an answer describing how to report a bug in the program and PPA he noticed. Then, as I noticed this problem myself, I reported it as a bug.

Should I change my answer to say that this has been reported as a bug, should I just leave a comment saying I've reported it, or should I create a new answer? Or does this question need to be closed since it is an actual bug?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just edit the answer to say something like:

> ***EDIT:***
>
> I noticed this problem myself.  I reported it as a bug at [where ever you reported it]

While technically questions about bugs are off-topic here I think its OK in this case (could be wrong)

Comment: You don't need the "EDIT:", it just makes things unreadable on the site, and there's an edit link above the editor's name.